# Benefit of using wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am going to create a website for just personal information.
In which i will going to add my information and projects done by me.
Pretty simple personal information website. 
In which there will be no blog. Which will be updated very less.

Pages what i expect is: 
Home
About
Portfolio
Contact

I am a freelancer so trying to get projects if possible.

So i need to know will wordpress will be useful for me?
Or just the HTML website will be beneficial in this case

Comment: No. Just write your own site. It gives you a much better image if you have a site you made yourself.

Comment: I agree with Niet ... do your own. Proof is in the pudding and all that. If you show you talent at the front end it has got to be better.

Comment: I think down voting this is unfair tbh he edited the down vote potion so give him a break

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis: He did not edit that out. I did.

Comment: The benefit of using wordpress over what? What are your alternatives? Do you now php, sql? Are you able to build a simple site by yourself including html, css and some javascript if necessary?

Comment: Why do people like downvote..:/ Instead of downvote can;t they just shrare their ideas. :(.
People getting cheap nowafdays.

Comment: @xbonez then I am glad someone experienced has got his back, the poor guy just needs a little advice is all

Comment: @PascalCuoq Last time i ask a topic question and they just downvote i think 5, i hate when people do it

Comment: @paz: You are getting downvoted because your question is unsuitable for StackOverflow. If you question requires "sharing of ideas", it is not for SO. SO is not a forum. It is a Q/A site. We avoid subjective questions.

Comment: @RafaSashi Yes, i know HTML, PHP, MYSQL, and designing in PSD as well.

Comment: @xbonez people in forum give bad or no usable ideas, i tried

Comment: @AnimusMiles-Militis The question is still off-topic even after someone else has edited the insulting “I know this is a bad question but please do not downvote it because I really need …” part.

Comment: @paz: Then look for a better forum. Bringing forum-like questions and then getting surprised when they get downvoted won't help you find an answer.

Comment: @PascalCuoq it is hardly insulting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use Wordpress for your jobs,

### Advantages:

1. If you donot want to write any code at all :) That's the biggest and the main benefit.
2. If you don't want to buy any kind of hosting, then you will come to wordpress. That's the second one.
3. You don't need to worry about bandwidth and Data.
4. Its a free CMS (content management system). Which will let you edit your site in the Browser, without having to know about HTML even a little bit.

### Disadvantages:

But at the same time you have many disadvantages of it too.

Such as

1. You will not be able to edit the template untill or unless you purchase it fully.
2. You won't be able to keep a good note on the stats, wordpress has its own builtin, but I don't like those!
3. You will have to stick to the features of wordpress, suppose you want to let your friends sign in and add comments you will require a Database, but wordpress won't let you install a new database.
4. Emails won't be allowed to or from any other service.

### Recommendation:

So what I would recommend you would be to either learn HTML and then start developing your own website and post it to the Net, or you can hire someone to create a website for you! But since you know HTML and are a freelancer, then good! You can create a simple site, with $1 fee and start your website.

### Basic Features:

You can create as many pages on wordpress too, but creating a website of your own will be much more like it. On wordpress you will be able to start a project which has all of these

1. About Page
2. Contact Page (only email address and social links can be provided, no forms!)
3. Portfolio
4. Pricing
5. And any other page required for the job...

You will be able to add plugins of your own desire, edit the template, edit fonts, or even do what so ever you like. You will be the webmaster of the website having no issue at all in editing or in coding.

You will be able to send and recieve emails too. With wordpress you can't do that! Wordpress won't let you have an Smtp server, so stoping you from sending emails! But with your own website, when you host it, you will send emails to your customers whenever the job is done! That's a good feature :)

### My Suggestion:

I'm a freelancer too, but that doesn't mean I should have a wordpress site only. Wordpress is a site that provides you a space to blog, you can ask for hires but then again you will have to partner with other sites like PayPal, then you'll have to manage the Email System using Gmail, then you'll have to take care of other stuffs too. Which Wordpress won't let you do. But if just want others to know about you, then yes! Wordpress is a good option for you. You can create a blog, and simply edit the details on it. Add Privacy, Terms, Pricing and all other stuff that is needed! You won't have to worry about the bandwidth too.

### My Blog on Wordpress:

I also have a wordpress blog for myself! Here it is hosted: http://templatesondemand.wordpress.com/

But it doesn't provide me with any customer at all, because of its lack in features. So on the other hand if I had a website of my own. I would have been hired atleast 5 times since then. So I just left this site as it is by posting vague stuff and adding a contact page only.

So, that's all that I can tell you! :) Now its you who will have to walk through the way :) .. (Whoa, that was alot of typing! :D..)

Good luck brother.

Comment: I'd like to point out that a lot of the limitations of WP can easily be overcome if you're willing to get your hands dirty with code. I agree that the WP codebase is inherently a massive mess, but it's still extensible.

Comment: True, anything can be done once you start coding :) Even you can create a simple app on Facebook and use it as your website, while your domain will be apps.facebook.com/yourappname and your data of Heroku! :D

Comment: Nice write-up and I recommend you publish it on your blog too. It's an awful Question for [so] standards and may be deleted in the future. That's why we should avoid answering off-topic Q's, we spend time and get some rep, just to lose it all when the Q is deleted.

Comment: You're right @brasofilo, but I just answered it to let him understand it :) However, you have a nice idea for me of writing it on my blog too :) Will copy paste it there..thanks man :)

Comment: Your good intentions are evident, but they send the wrong signal that people can *knowingly* ask off-topic Q and get an Answer before it's closed. . . . . I've got a couple of WP/Stack plugins linked in my profile that you may like :)

Comment: You've got a point :) I will keep your advice in mind..and sure I will have a look at them :) thanks..